# Constraintlayout, view pushed outside bounds

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need to achieve the following layout:

[image]

The title 'Trouble in paradise should be able to expand in height but it shouldn't push 'Ma 21januari' outside of the bounds.

This is my layout at the moment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/wrapper_titles"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_episode"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_episode"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_episode"
      >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_episode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title_episode"
        tools:text="Ma 21 januari"
        style="@style/Text_Episode_Subtitle"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_episode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Trouble in paradise"
        style="@style/Text_Episode_Title"
        />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I make title_episode expand to the full height but with subtitle_episode still fixed to the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution would be to put both `TextViews` in a packed vertical chain with bias set to `1` so that they stick to the bottom. This means that you need to add `top` constraints for these `TextViews` which will also help to prevent them from getting pushed outside. Since the `title_episode's` height is set to `wrap_content`, it's also important to set the `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` attribute to enforce its constraints as it expands.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper_titles"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_episode"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_episode"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_episode"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_episode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/title_episode"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Ma 21 januari"
        style="@style/Text_Episode_Subtitle"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_episode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subtitle_episode"
        tools:text="Trouble in paradise"
        style="@style/Text_Episode_Title"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect, this does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I've provided a basic structure meeting your requirements, customize according to your need:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_episode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        tools:text="Ma 21 januari" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_episode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subtitle_episode"
        tools:text="Trouble in paradise Trouble in paradise Trouble in paradise" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, take a look:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_episode"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_episode"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_episode">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_episode"
        style="@style/Text_Episode_Subtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Ma 21 januari" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_episode"
        style="@style/Text_Episode_Title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subtitle_episode"
        tools:text="Trouble in paradise Trouble in paradise" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]